# In R/Shiny how to make inputs have the same name of actionButton

Tags: r, shiny

I have a code that once I click on the option of my selectInput widget the input value is the names that are showed on the options.

I would like to make the same thing with my actionLink button but the input in this case is the sum of clicks. Is it possible to change the inputs values?

This is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$div(
    id = "sidebar",
    class = "sidebar",

    selectInput(
      inputId = "custom_select",
      label = "Clubs",
      choices = names(mtcars),
      selectize = F,
      size = 5,

      width = "300px"
    ),

    div(
      names(mtcars) %>% map(~.x %>% actionLink(inputId = .x)))
  ),

  h1(htmlOutput(outputId = 'title')),

  h1(htmlOutput(outputId = 'title2')))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$title <- renderUI({

    input$custom_select

  })
  output$title2 <- renderUI({

    input[[names(mtcars)[1]]]

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see the output is the number of clicks.

For the selectInput widget it works fine.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I got you right but using an `observeEvent` you could do:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$div(
    id = "sidebar",
    class = "sidebar",
    selectInput(
      inputId = "custom_select",
      label = "Clubs",
      choices = names(mtcars),
      selectize = F,
      size = 5,
      width = "300px"
    ),
    div(
      names(mtcars) %>% map(~ .x %>% actionLink(inputId = .x))
    )
  ),
  h1(htmlOutput(outputId = "title")),
  h1(htmlOutput(outputId = "title2"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$title <- renderUI({
    input$custom_select
  })
  lapply(names(mtcars), function(x) {
    observeEvent(input[[x]], {
      output$title2 <- renderUI({
        paste(x, input[[x]], sep = ": ")
      })  
    })  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]